# Visual Studio IDE - Removes heading 0's from my code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, formatting, ide, hex

When I write a hex value in my VB.NET code, I want it to look like this:

`&H0F` (Binary: `&B00001111`)

but instead, Visual Studio makes it (imo) unreadable by removing the leading 0's:

`&HF` (Binary: `&B1111`)

That way, I cant see easily whether it's a byte, a short, etc.

**So my question is:** Is there a setting in the Visual Studio IDE that disables this "feature"?
I really want to keep those 0's.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Isn't the member type declaration telling you the type of the value? Or, e.g., `dim someThing1 = &HFL dim someThing2 = &HFS`. The first is Long, the other Short, etc. Or `dim someThing1& = &HF dim someThing2! = &HF`. `&H000000F` doesn't actually say what the type is.

Comment: The leading zero doesn't change the type so it doesn't help you determine the type. Both `&HF` and `&H0F` are type `Integer`. The only way you could make it a `Byte` is assign it to a `Byte` variable so, as suggested, you're trying to make the the IDE tell you something that is either not true or else is obvious regardless.

Comment: I know that, but I personally read binary and hex from left to right and thus, if I dont see leading zeros, my brain assumes that those are the leading digits. Means: My brain interprets `&HF` as `&B11110000`, for a byte. Thats why I want to make it clear for myself and I usually write the 0's as well.

Comment: `dim someThing as Byte = &HF`. You cannot be mistaken. You need to know what `someThing` is (its Type), not what `&HF` might represent.

Comment: Also, it's clear that the *missing* `0`s would have been placed on the left, `&HF000` preserves the `0`s, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS2017 and above: if you use the group separator **_** (underscore character),  the leading zeros will not be removed by the editor. See: [Hexadecimal, binary, and octal literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters#hexadecimal-binary-and-octal-literals)

Note that the group separator adds no intrinsic meaning to value; they are just meaningless formatting characters . What I mean by that is that only the digits are preserved when it is evaluated by the parser.  Think of it as all "_" are removed from the string before evaluating. So, `&B1_1_1_1` is the same as `&B1________________1_1_1`.

Some Examples:

```
  Dim b As Byte
  b = &B0000_1111
  b = &B0_0_0_0_1_1_1_1
  b = &H0_F
```

Comment: Still very ugly but helpful. Thank you!